# Need to remove the root directory from a file path

Tags: shell

I need to remove the root directory from a file path. Below is the example for the same,

path1=/tmp/errorlog_invest_12345_88_1:05:45.txt

Output:

The root directory here is /tmp/

Moreover i wanted to do this in a dynamic manner i.e. identify the root directory for any file path given.

Kindly help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: By "root directory" do you only mean the first directory in the path? I.e., for the input of "/a/b/file.txt", what would you want to get? "b/file.txt" or "file.txt"?

Comment: You want to do this on Linux, Mac, Windows... ?

Comment: Thanks. The root directory for the given input is "/a/b/", that "file.txt" can be anything, it depends completely on the user who gives input.

Comment: I want to do this in linux. Kindly help me on this

Comment: Does this mean you want to get just the filename? If so, use `basename`: `name=$(basename /tmp/whatever/some_file.txt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your string, you're probably using bash.

You can split the "root" from the path with the dirname -command. Example:

dirname /tmp/errorlog_invest_12345_88_1:05:45.txt

This should print: tmp
... as result.

Comment: This command, however, prints the "whole path" to the directory, not just the actual root level directory. Ie, if the path is"/tmp/files/somefile.txt" the result will be: /tmp/files

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$ path1=/tmp/errorlog_invest_12345_88_1:05:45.txt
$ file=${path1##*/}
$ echo $file
errorlog_invest_12345_88_1:05:45.txt
$ dir=${path1%/$file}
$ echo $dir
/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a file path as

```
filepath=dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
```

**Pay attention to the basedirectory dir1 and not /dir1**

Depending on where your filepath has first '/' you can adjust $n value in print subcommand in one liner below.

Ok, assuming  your filepath is as above, one line command to delete the basedirectory will be

```
rm -rf $(echo "$filepath" | awk -F "/" '{print $1}')
```

This will delete the base directory dir1 and all its subdirectories and files in the directory tree.